# in Canasta, is it allowed to pick up from a frozen pile?

Tags: canasta

In classic Canasta, if I have a dirty canasta in 10s and someone discards a 10, can I pick it up from a frozen pile?

Comment: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/40083/canasta-rules-to-pick-up-discard-pile-when-frozen-or-not-frozen?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

If the pile is frozen, you must have two more tens in your hand in order to pick up the discard pile. If the discard pile were not frozen, you could pick up the discard pile as long as you can meld the top card at all. This is the only difference between a frozen and non-frozen discard pile.